# Sum of correlated log-normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, bivariate-distributions

Suppose $P(x_1,x_2)$ is the pdf of a bivariate normal distribution, where $x_1\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $x_2\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ and the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is $\rho$.

I am looking for a closed-form formula or an approximation of the pdf of the RV:
$$
Y = \exp{x_1} + \exp{x_2}\,.
$$

As far as I know there is probably only an approximation, but I can only find an approximation in the case $\rho=0$, i.e. when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent.

Any ideas?

Thanks!